# FIDO2/WebAuthn "This security key doesn't look familiar."

Tags: webauthn, fido-u2f, yubikey

I am playing with a YubiKey and JavaScript in-browser WebAuthn APIs. I am trying a very minimal "Hello, World!" example which just tries to do a minimal: `navigator.credentials.create` and then a `navigator.credentials.get` (with minimal, even hard-coded values to just demonstration.

The `create` works fine - but the `get` always results in an error:

> This security key doesn't look familiar.

I am having a hard time understanding what even theoretically might cause this. For example, to my knowledge the YubiKey doesn't actually *store* credentials on it - but rather requires the server to send back an encrypted opaque bundle containing the key.

But the `get` API only *requires* a cryptographic `challenge`. (I think this is just random data from the server, and not the encrypted key?) (I am basically sending all zeros for the challenge, for now).

Examples show the `allowCredentails` (which is an *optional* field) sending one (or more) ID's back. It make sense that if the IDs themselves were the encrypted keys, it should use those. (But they're again *optional*) and I still get this error even if I specify the same Id (in a ByteArray) which was returned from the `create`, or if I give NO Id's whatsoever.

So what *could* the problem be? Is it that I'm supposed to be sending something with the challenge? Is my `id` requried, but perhaps malformed? I've noticed other examples sending *many* `allowCredential` IDs (I have no idea where these are coming from, because only *one* matches the one from it's original enrollment).

Is there something I am fundamentally missing here?

Comment: Can you include some code samples? It'd be useful to see in particular what you're passing to `navigator.credentials.get()`

Comment: @IAmKale I got past that - will post answer - but now having problems in Duo webauthn golang server code ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer *appears* to be (from the best I could resolve):

Yubikey does not *store* credentials, so the ID (passed back from the server during login) must *encode* the (encrypted private key) credentials - to be handed back to they authenticator (Yubikey) itself. If this isn't done (correctly) you will get an error saying the key is not recognized. Since the spec allows for you to pass no `allowCredentials` back in the `get` (login) phase - I would *assume* this means there *may* be a facility for an authenticator to *store* a key on it - though this is not commonly done, (or by Yubikey)?

Either way - in my case, the ID must be passed back, and correctly. My particular issue was that the ID returned during *create* is expressed as string - which is *kind of* base64 encoded, but has some oddities in the encoding - and when I was converting it back to an ArrayBuffer for the `get` - I didn't get it exactly right.

The nonstandard base64 format needs some characters to be replaced before the base64 conversion:

`thing = thing.replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/");`

Comment: The "nonstandard base64" that WebAuthn uses is called Base64URL - see the first item on https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-dependencies

Comment: Here's more info on it if you're interested https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5